# ThinkingSphinx3: Just upgraded from TS2 & getting odd sort_by error message

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have the following attribute in my Ad model:

```
has sort_by_date, :as => :timestamp, :sortable => true
```

In the ads table there is a sort_by_date field, which is a datetime field.

However when I search, passing the following as my :order option (I want to show newer ads first & then sort by relevance)

```
:order => "sort_by_date DESC, @weight DESC"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (index ad_core: sort-by attribute 'sort_by_date' not found):
```

Can anyone see why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run ts:rebuild since adding that attribute?

Comment: @pat - yes, I've ran it a bunch of times, everything looks like it should work, do you think I need to convert the sort_by_date field in my db from a datetime to a timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got this working by changing my sort_by_date field in the database from a datetime to a timestamp, hope this helps someone else out.